# Primefaces dialog backing bean randomly not called

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog

Primefaces 7 on JBoss 7.3
I have an application which allows users to click on entries in a datatable to display details of the entity in a dialog box:

```
<p:column headerText="XTAMessageID" id="msgIdCol" width="350" sortBy="#{nachricht.messageId}" styleClass="column">
    
    <p:commandLink value="#{nachricht.messageId}" id="transportReportLink"
        oncomplete="PF('transportDialogDC').show()"
        action="#{detailController.showTransportReport(nachricht)}"
        update="@form:transportDialogDC"></p:commandLink>
<p:tooltip for="transportReportLink" value="Transport Report anzeigen" position="top"></p:tooltip>
</p:column>



<p:dialog id="transportDialogDC" widgetVar="transportDialogDC" styleClass="messageDialog">
    <p:growl life="10000"></p:growl>
<p>MessageId: #{detailController.messagedId} von: #{detailController.absender} an: #{detailController.empfaenger}</p>
<p:panelGrid columns="2" style="border-width:0px !important">
    <p:panel style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; border-width:0px !important">
    <h4>Transport Report</h4>
    
    <h:inputTextarea value="#{detailController.transportReportXML}" readonly="true" styleClass="messageDialogTextArea" cols="100" rows="25"/>
    </p:panel>
…..
```

In Chrome this works, however in Firefox (98) sometimes the dialog is displayed empty without calling the detailController.showTransportReport(nachricht) method. Nothing happens in the backend....
This behavior persists for a few trials. After reloading the pages the dialog works again for a random number of times.

Any ideas what might cause this?

Thanks,

Hans

Comment: Can you please try to replicate this with https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces-test? If it's a bug, it should be reported and addressed.